# Export data from H2 database into CSV

Tags: csv, h2

I have a stand alone H2 server up and running gathering data. For testing I want to get data out my server into a CSV file. Are there any tools for that?

Comment: Did you check: http://www.h2database.com/html/links.html#tools

Comment: H2 has a function to write CSV files. Check [CSVWRITE](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvwrite).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

## Try `CSVWRITE`

This is perhaps all that you need:

```
call CSVWRITE ( 'C:/MyFolder/MyCSV.txt', 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE' )
```

You need to just run the call (mentioned above) in the browser based client of H2 that you are most likely using.

Further reading:
http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvwrite.

Comment: Probably because the H2 Help command doesn't have any function resembling the term 'export'.  I guess you just have to know to look for 'CSV'.  See also http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#script

Answer (score 9):

For small data, you can also use `script` to export any table:

`script table <table_name>`

Comment: Nice answer, but this command produces SQL statements, not a CSV file as requested in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Another way works for me:

```
script SIMPLE to 'C:\FolderName\FileName.sql' table SCHEMA.TABLENAME;
```